# How to control a motor with a photoresistor

Tags: dc-motor, photoresistor

I have a little 2 to 5 volt hobby motor that I would like to control with a photoresistor aka photocell.  What is the simplest way to control the circuit?  Is there a photo resistor with enough range to be the only element inthe battery motor series circuit?  So that I can just turn off the motor by the photoresistor resistance going high enough?  Or do I need a voltage divider with the motor in parallel with the larger resistor, so that the photoresistor can take voltage away form the larger resistor as the photoresistor resistance approaches the larger resistor?  This is for a project for my kids school, so I want it to be really simple.  Does a motor have a resistance when on or off?

Comment: The "on" resistance will almost certainly be too high for this to work without a transistor.

Comment: Why can I control the motor with a pot in series?  Would I not be able to get a photoresistor with a similar resistance range as the pot?  And thus also be able to control he motor?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92402/how-do-i-build-a-light-activated-motor

Comment: Does it have to be a photoresistor, or does it just need to respond to light? A photovoltaic panel would be even simpler -- you don't even need a battery.

Comment: It just needs to respond to light.  The photovoltaic panel or solar cell would be great, but I can only find them priced at no lower than $7 per.  I need to buy 20 for the whole class, making that solution cost prohibitive.

Comment: @pjc50 can I use just a phototransistor?

Comment: A photo transistor may be enough.  We need to know how much current the DC motor needs.  (Stall current and run current maybe.. what does the motor have to do?)  (Do they make darlington photo-transistors?)

Comment: Motor + solar cell combo for $2: http://www.dx.com/p/world-s-smallest-solar-powered-car-37373

Comment: @pcj50 , that is the greatest website!  This was my order, surely one of these will let the kids have some fun.  thanks!  What do I do to mark an answer on this site?: 

 World's Smallest Solar Powered Car 
  US$ 2.37 2 US$ 4.74
 Novel Solar Powered Locust 
  US$ 2.81 Solar Powered Toys Educational DIY Kit Set (6-Model) 
  US$ 6.44
 Novel Solar Powered Cockroach (Black) US$ 2.57 2 US$ 5.14
 Si Solar Cell Panel (4.5V 5mA) US$ 3.69 1 US$ 3.69
 BONATECH 03120269 Phototransistor - Silver + Golden (2 PCS) US$ 2.18
 TCRT5000 Reflective Infrared Sensor Photoelectric Switches (10 PCS) US$ 4.35

Comment: @GeorgeHerold , this is the motor ordered from MCM electronics. 28-12811 - Compact 12,000 RPM Hobby Motor 1.5V ~ 3V DC . I used it to let the kids make artbots: http://www.kiwicrate.com/projects/Motorized-ArtBot-Robot/224  Now I want to add one more level of complexity to the project by adding either a pot to the circuit (so the artbot moves at differing speeds), or to have the artbot respond to light (by adding the phototransistor in series).  With this information, do you think the phototransistor in series will work?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold  http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/28-12811?utm_source=transactionalemail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ConfirmEmail

Comment: @statHacker, OK you need something on the order of an amp of current.  None of these will be enough, http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/sensors-transducers/optical-sensors-phototransistors/1967049?k=phototransistor  I didn't see an darlington photo-transistors, so you'd have to make your own.  Maybe a 30mA photo transistor and a medium power npn (I like TIP31's)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold thanks for your idea.  The tricky part about this problem is it is for my 5 yo kid.  So ideally I would want to introduce a single circuit component so they would understand the power of understanding the parts of the circuit and how it allows you to "control their world" as is the goal of any self-respecting hacker.  I like the idea of the dissecting out the parts of the solar car per above.  If you have any other ideas to expand on the simple battery motor circuit with just a single component that a kid could connect with a couple of twists of wire, that would be very cool.

Answer (score 1):

OK rather than continuing comments I'll answer here.
For kids only five years old this will be a bit much I think.
I'd start with just batteries and light bulbs... How do you make the light turn on?
You can then do some series and parallel stuff.  But even that may be over the top for some.. maybe best to just let them play around..  (How many different can you get a light bulb to turn on.)  If you wanted you could add some LED's to the mix.  (Maybe with the current limiting resistor soldered onto on leg and covered with heat shrink.)  I can think of lots of fun things... but again may not when they are only 5.  (A red and a green/blue LED in parallel would be interesting.)